# Unable to load class payum in Laravel 4

Tags: payum

I have installed payum for laravel 4 but it don't get registred in my app

In my controller

```
$storage = $this->getPayum()->getStorage('Payum\Core\Model\ArrayObject');
```

I get the error

```
ReflectionException: Class payum does not exist
```

I have gone through the directions at http://payum.org/doc/0.9/PayumLaravelPackage/get-it-started.

My composer.json:

```
    "payum/payex": "*@stable",
    "payum/payum-laravel-package": "*@stable",
    "payum/paypal-express-checkout-nvp": "*@stable"
```

**My questions is:**

- Is there any known issues for payum in laravel 4?
- Is there any workaround?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The package is expected to work (at least 0.9 version and above). There is a sandbox https://github.com/makasim/PayumLaravelBundleSandbox, which works well for me. Could you look at it and compare with your setup

Comment: Ok thanks! When I looked at sandbox code I finally found that autoloading of Payum was missing in app.php.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved it add 'Payum\LaravelPackage\PayumServiceProvider' to app/config/app.php file.

```
'providers' => array(
     ...      
     //All yours providers
    'Payum\LaravelPackage\PayumServiceProvider',
),
```

I hope it help you.